# How to extract item from a list if a match is found and add to a new list?

Tags: java, android

Say I have a List as follows;

Create list;

```
 final List<WifiNetworkSuggestion> result = wifiManager.getNetworkSuggestions();
```

Result of list;

```
[WifiNetworkSuggestion[ SSID="Test123", BSSID=null, FQDN=null, isAppInteractionRequired=false, isUserInteractionRequired=false, isCredentialSharedWithUser=true, isInitialAutoJoinEnabled=true, isUnTrusted=false ], [ SSID="Test12345", BSSID=null, FQDN=null, isAppInteractionRequired=false, isUserInteractionRequired=false, isCredentialSharedWithUser=true, isInitialAutoJoinEnabled=true, isUnTrusted=false ]]
```

There could be more than one list object here with a different SSID's as shown above.

How can I only extract the list object where SSID="Test123" is found and put into a new list with that list object alone but keep the same convention.  For example, I want my new list to be like;

```
[WifiNetworkSuggestion[ SSID="Test123", BSSID=null, FQDN=null, isAppInteractionRequired=false, isUserInteractionRequired=false, isCredentialSharedWithUser=true, isInitialAutoJoinEnabled=true, isUnTrusted=false ]]
```

I thought of amending the current list by removing what I don't want;

```
result.removeIf(list -> !list.contains("SSID="Test123""));
```

but to no avail.

**EDIT**

If I use a stream as suggested, how can I only get the list object I want?

```
List<WifiNetworkSuggestion> flat = 
result.stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#getNetworkSuggestions()

Comment: Hi, you can use stream (if your java version is 8 or higher) with filter operation and collect the result in a new list

Comment: I could use a stream, was just looking at it.  I can figure out how to convert the entire list into a single list but not how to extract the single list I need. If that makes sense.. I edited my question above.

Comment: Could you please put the code of WifiNetworkSuggestion class to understand how the list is structured?

Comment: WifiNetworkSuggestion is not a custom class that I have written.  I have added a URL to the actual docs from Android. 

The app can create multiple of these 'configuration' and each one gets added to this list and when I query it, it returns a list in a list as shown above. 

I want to only get one list that contains a specific SSID and put into a new list so it can be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `filter()` method of the Stream API.

```
Stream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate)
```

An example would look like the following:

```
List<WifiNetworkSuggestion> newList= result
    .stream()
    .filter(suggestion-> "Test123".equals(suggestion.getSsid()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The `filter()` method is taking a predicate. And only items with an SSID equal to "Test123" are passing by this filter.

Documentation of `Stream.filter()`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-

Comment: Will give this a shot in a bit.  I'll let you know how I get on - thanks for that.

Comment: Did the trick - nice one! Must read up on this - havent used it before.

Comment: a good presentation of Lambda and stream :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OpAgZvYXLQ